# How to instantiate object with non-nullable property, for later update

Tags: c#

Trying to avoid creating separate DTOs for my one really simple post in this app. I have a required property on my entity that is a reference to another entity. This is the user, which is grabbed later by the authentication/authorization and populated.

Except... I can't get past the instantiation in the controller because it's a non-nullable property.

```
public class MyModel {
    public UserModel User { get; set; } = null!;
}

public IActionResult Submit(MyModel model){
    model.User = CurrentUser; // <- can't get here.
}
```

> 0: "The User field is required."

I was under the impression that the `= null!` would allow the model to instantiate and not care that it's "`null`" until I try to utilize it later? I may be misunderstanding that functionality significantly.

I'd very much like to:

- Keep this property not-nullable.
- Not have to create a second class to handle post data without this property

Is this possible?

Comment: How the null enforcing is configured? With `[NotNull]` annotation?

Comment: can you show the DI in your startup/program.cs ?

Comment: There is nothing in the C# language that would produce that error message. Can you show more about where/how you got that error message? Is it an exception? If so, can you share the stacktrace? Let me rephrase that. Your class can be instantiated, and calling the `Submit` method with an existing `Model` instance will set the `User` property to whatever `CurrentUser` is. You can either configure the compiler to give warnings when mixing non-null variables with (potentially) null references, or you can configure it to produce an error, but at runtime it is all the same.

Comment: "The null-forgiving operator has no effect at run time." re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the error message is what I'm getting in the response to the post

Comment: Then that is part of some validation framework or whatnot.

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa not sure really, there's no annotations on it

Comment: I don't have time to fully delve into this but perhaps pattern matching
`if (model.User is UserModel user){/* do something with user */  }` helps avoid this type of thing: `if(user != null){`

Comment: @RandyHall fyi, I voted this question up as I thought it was a good, well written, informative question. I don't know why, but C# seems to have the most polarized audience that will down vote a question/answer simply because they don't agree with it. I believe everyone is entitled to their own opinion, whether I like it or not, and that should be discussed in comments, not in up/down votes. Votes for questions should be reserved to readability, reproducibility, and how helpful it is / how much work went into it. Votes for answers should be based on relevance, accuracy, and usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use a property with a backing field?

```cs
public class MyModel {

    [CanBeNull]
    private UserModel _User = null;

    public UserModel User 
    { 
        get { return _User ?? throw new System.InvalidOperationException("_User is has not been set yet"); }
        set { _User = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to initialize the property to some valid value. The point of non-nullable is that it can **never** be null.

My only suggestions would be to either

1. let the value be null, and initialize as such, but edit set operator to throw ArgumentNullException if given null value later,
2. define `User.Null` to be a non-existent `User`, used for "initialization", or
3. change your class to enable passing value to UserModel during initialization and create MyModel in Submit as output parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no guarantee in .NET or C# that a non-nullable property using the new nullable references can **never** be null. It is **intended never** to be null. But it can be.

Comment: @Lasse Technically yes, but the point of non-nullable is that is should not be null. Enabling the value to ever be null defeats the whole purpose of the Nullable system, which is to reduce chances of bugs and thus simplify testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a default value.

If the instance you are receiving is null, it will create a new instance of `User`, else it will contain your non-null instance.

```
public class MyModel {
    public UserModel User { get; set; } = new User();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are probably using Net 6. You can remove option nullable from project configuration. This way you don't need to do a stupid job to mark all  default nullabble  properties all your classes  as nullable

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>   <!-- change from enable -->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I agree this new "nullable" feature is very annoying when it comes to "upgrading" code to newer .NET version. It would have been better to require adding `!` to variable types to indicate it cannot be null rather than needing to add `#nullable disable` to each file.

Comment: That "annoying" feature can saves you countless hours of headaches down the road if you invest the time doing the "stupid" job to account for it.

Comment: @Joe my point was it creates a lot of work when upgrading code, not that I don't like the feature.

Comment: @Adam It sure does create a lot of work.  And along the way it allows you to fix countless potential bugs and crashes you never knew were there.   I cannot say I ever enjoyed making my code nullable-correct.  Nor do I  enjoy writing unit tests, making C++ code const-correct, etc.  But I have never for a second regretted doing any of them.  And the mindset that thinks of any of these tasks as "stupid" (not your words, I realize) is one to be avoided like the plague

Comment: I've been getting paid for coding since I wrote assembler in the 80s, @Serge   I've worked with plenty of people who could not be bothered with unsexy tasks that help to bullet proof the code.  It became too much work to fix their code and write my own.  Finding one developer who "gets it" is worth ten of them.

Comment: @Joe It will be not a bullet proof. On the contrary, if you have few properties,  it is a mess that even hard to read. Only ? everywhere. It doesn't make any common sense even.  These microsoft kids even don't realize that there are used nullable properties in 99 percent classes

Comment: It forces you to *address every case*.  Whether a reference may be null or not.  Without `nullable ` enabled, if you declare a reference and fail to initialize it, the compiler doesn't care.  If someone down the line doesn't know the rules, hello crash.  With it enabled, you must either mark (and be forced to at least consider it) or *not* mark it as nullable and then be forced to initialize it.  The quantity of avoided `NullReferenceException`s  saves days.  Not just for your code, but for all the new developers on the team, maybe junior ones who don't have a lifetime of good habits.

Comment: @Serge I did not downvote your answer, but somebody just made a downvote run against questions/answers I posted that have been dead for weeks.

Comment: @RandyHall the same with my questions/asnwers If the answer  has not vouted up, it will be certainly vouted down. Doesn't matter how your answer is good. This happens with the most my answers.

Comment: @Serge this only happens to me with C# questions, no other language I've worked with I've had this many issues with. Half my C# questions get downvoted into oblivion with zero explanation. Obviously I'm not that bad, given my overall rep. Literally never had to delete a question outside of C#.

Comment: I downvoted your answer.  Because I think it is terrible advice to advise people against modern coding aids that allow you to avoid at compile time bugs that used to only be discovered at runtime.